# Can you automatically italicize a name of a company or other string of words throughout your entire latex document by using a built in Latex function?

Tags: formatting

I am writing a report in Latex and I need a specific string of words (a company's name) to be italicized throughout the whole document. How can I do this without manually using the \textit or \emph functions

Comment: Wouldn't a simple search & replace in your editor do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a command for that. For instance

```
\newcommand{\nyt}{\textit{New York Tires}}
```

Then, you type something like `The \nyt\ was founded in 1907`.

If you load the `\xspace` package, then the definition could be

```
\newcommand{\nyt}{\textit{New York Tires}\xspace}
```

and then you could just type `The \nyt was founded in 1907`.